# Is it possible to execute `composer dump-autoload` automatically after installing my package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I wrote a Laravel package that I want to make available for everyone to download.

However, it seems that I have to manually execute `composer dump-autoload` after I add my package.

Is it possible to automatically execute `composer dump-autoload` after the install so that the composer will autoload all the new classes in my project?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can add it in the "post-update" script section of your `composer.json`. It'll then be executed after every update of the project. You can also add it inside the "post-install" section, so the command will be called directly after the installation.

A short excerpt from a composer.json:

```
"scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "composer dump-autoload", // Here.
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "composer dump-autoload" // Here too.
        ]
    },
```